# How do I get the current datasource filter for a grid with Kendo UI for Vue?

Tags: kendo-ui, vue.js

To get the current datasource filter with Kendo UI for jQuery, [you can call dataSource.filter()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter)

I can't seem to find the equivalent for the Vue.js version. I've created an example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8rk0Jkd0AN7TqV1Xvj79?p=preview). The filter is currently set on the 'ProductName' column to show results that start with 'c' via:

```
filterConfiguration: { field: "ProductName", operator: "startswith", value: "c" },
```

You can see this in the console by clicking the Log Filter button which logs out the value of:

```
this.$refs.localDataSource.filter
```

If you change the filter by clicking on the column header and changing 'c' to 'ch' you'll notice if you log the filter again, it does not change.
There is also no filter() function on the data source. Is there a way to get the currently applied filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to assign the filter object like this:

```
    filterConfiguration: {
       logic: "or",
       filters: [
         { field: "ProductName", operator: "startswith", value: "c" }
       ]
     }
```

Or if you don't want to load the grid with any preset filters, you need at least  this:

```
    filterConfiguration: {
        filters: []
     }
```

This will not work:

```
    filterConfiguration: {}
```